# How to add an observable property when other properties change

Tags: swiftui, combine

I have the following model object that I use to populate a `List` with a `Toggle` for each row, which is bound to `measurement.isSelected`

```
final class Model: ObservableObject {

    struct Measurement: Identifiable {
        var id = UUID()
        let name: String
        var isSelected: Binding<Bool>

        var selected: Bool = false

        init(name: String) {
            self.name = name

            let selected = CurrentValueSubject<Bool, Never>(false)
            self.isSelected = Binding<Bool>(get: { selected.value }, set: { selected.value = $0 })
        }
    }

    @Published var measurements: [Measurement]
    @Published var hasSelection: Bool = false  // How to set this?

    init(measurements: [Measurement]) {
        self.measurements = measurements
    }
}
```

I'd like the `hasSelection` property to be true whenever any `measurement.isSelected` is `true`. I'm guessing somehow `Model` needs to observe changes in `measurements` and then update its `hasSelection` property… but I've no idea where to start!

The idea is that `hasSelection` will be bound to a `Button` to enable or disable it.

---

`Model` is used as follows…

```
struct MeasurementsView: View {

    @ObservedObject var model: Model

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(model.measurements) { measurement in
                MeasurementView(measurement: measurement)
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Select Measurements")
            .navigationBarItems(trailing: NavigationLink(destination: NextView(), isActive: $model.hasSelection, label: {
                Text("Next")
            }))
        }
    }
}

struct MeasurementView: View {
    let measurement: Model.Measurement
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text(measurement.name)
                .font(.subheadline)
            Spacer()
            Toggle(measurement.name, isOn: measurement.isSelected)
                .labelsHidden()
        }
    }
}
```

---

For info, here's a screenshot of what I'm trying to achieve. A list of selectable items, with a navigation link that is enabled when one or more is selected, and disabled when no items are selected.

[image]

Comment: could you please provide an example of how your are using your model?

Comment: @AshleyMills let say with the button is set hasSelection to true. which of isSelected value has to be changed? this is 1:N link between hasSelection and isSelected. the opposite is easy, hasSelection  could be calculated on demand

Comment: @user3441734 `hasSelection` should ideally be a get only property, that is true if  _any_ of `measurement.isSelected` is true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> @user3441734 hasSelection should ideally be a get only property, that
>   is true if any of measurement.isSelected is true

```
struct Data {
    var bool: Bool
}
class Model: ObservableObject {
    @Published var arr: [Data] = []
    var anyTrue: Bool {
        arr.map{$0.bool}.contains(true)
    }
}
```

example (as before) copy - paste - run

```
import SwiftUI

struct Data: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var name: String
    var on_off: Bool
}

class Model: ObservableObject {
    @Published var data = [Data(name: "alfa", on_off: false), Data(name: "beta", on_off: false), Data(name: "gama", on_off: false)]
    var bool: Bool {
        data.map {$0.on_off} .contains(true)
    }
}



struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var model = Model()
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
        List(0 ..< model.data.count) { idx in
            HStack {
                Text(verbatim: self.model.data[idx].name)
                Toggle(isOn: self.$model.data[idx].on_off) {
                    EmptyView()
                }
            }
        }
            Text("\(model.bool.description)").font(.largeTitle).padding()
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

When the model.data is updated

```
@Published var data ....
```

its publisher calls `objectWillChange` on `ObservableObject`.

Next SwiftUI recognize that `ObservedObject` needs the View to be "updated". The View is recreated, and that will force the `model.bool.description` will have fresh value.

**LAST UPDATE**

change this part of code

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var model = Model()
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
        List(0 ..< model.data.count) { idx in
            HStack {
                Text(verbatim: self.model.data[idx].name)
                Toggle(isOn: self.$model.data[idx].on_off) {
                    EmptyView()
                }
            }
            }.navigationBarTitle("List")
            .navigationBarItems(trailing:

                NavigationLink(destination: Text("next"), label: {
                    Text("Next")
                }).disabled(!model.bool)

            )
        }
    }
}
```

and it is EXACTLY, WHAT YOU HAVE in your updated question
[image]

**Try it on real device, otherwise the NavigationLink is usable only once (this is well known simulator bug in current Xcode 11.3.1 (11C504)).**

Comment: In you answer, will `anyTrue` be updated when a member of `arr` is set to true and publish its state?

Comment: @AshleyMills updated, with the example from your previous question

Comment: @AshleyMills why it works is explained too in my updated answer

Comment: In my example, I want to use the `hasSelection` property to enable/disable a `NavigationLink`, so it has to be `Binding<Bool>`, not just a plain `Bool`

Comment: @AshleyMills see the Toggle in the example, it use Binding<Bool>, wich is what you want, isn't it?

Comment: @AshleyMills which version of NavigationLink use some Binding<Bool> to enable / disable it?

Comment: @AshleyMills I checked your updated question. Did you try my example? Because it is exactly what you are asking for ...

Comment: @AshleyMills see the video and "updated" example. If it still doesn't meet your requirements as written in your question, let me know ...

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you very much - it was the `.disabled()` modifier I was missing.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code at the moment is that even if you observe the changes to `measurements`, they will not get updated when the selection updates, because you declared the `var isSelected: Binding<Bool>` as a Binding. This means that SwiftUI is storing it outside of your struct, and the struct itself doesn't update (stays immutable).

What you could try instead is declaring `@Published var selectedMeasurementId: UUID? = nil` on your model So your code would be something like this:

```swift
import SwiftUI
import Combine

struct NextView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Next View")

    }
}

struct MeasurementsView: View {

    @ObservedObject var model: Model

    var body: some View {

        let hasSelection = Binding<Bool> (
            get: {
                self.model.selectedMeasurementId != nil
            },
            set: { value in
                self.model.selectedMeasurementId = nil
            }
        )

        return NavigationView {
            List(model.measurements) { measurement in
                MeasurementView(measurement: measurement, selectedMeasurementId: self.$model.selectedMeasurementId)
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Select Measurements")
            .navigationBarItems(trailing: NavigationLink(destination: NextView(), isActive: hasSelection, label: {
                Text("Next")
            }))
        }
    }
}

struct MeasurementView: View {


    let measurement: Model.Measurement
    @Binding var selectedMeasurementId: UUID?

    var body: some View {

        let isSelected = Binding<Bool>(
            get: {
                self.selectedMeasurementId == self.measurement.id
            },
            set: { value in
                if value {
                    self.selectedMeasurementId = self.measurement.id
                } else {
                    self.selectedMeasurementId = nil
                }
            }
        )

        return HStack {
            Text(measurement.name)
                .font(.subheadline)
            Spacer()
            Toggle(measurement.name, isOn: isSelected)
                .labelsHidden()
        }
    }
}

final class Model: ObservableObject {

    @Published var selectedMeasurementId: UUID? = nil

    struct Measurement: Identifiable {
        var id = UUID()
        let name: String

        init(name: String) {
            self.name = name
        }
    }

    @Published var measurements: [Measurement]


    init(measurements: [Measurement]) {
        self.measurements = measurements
    }
}
```

I'm not sure exactly how you want the navigation button in the navbar to behave. For now I just set the selection to nil when it's tapped. You can modify it depending on what you want to do.

If you want to support multi-selection, you can use a Set of selected ids instead.

Also, seems like the iOS simulator has some problems with navigation, but I tested on a physical device and it worked.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer - I've added a screenshot and more info to the question so you can see what I'm trying to achieve.